# Where is error in ftp-bat script?

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I scripting automatic ftp script.

And throws error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

User (domain.lt:(none)):

Error reading password.

Login incorrect.
Login failed.
```

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
mkdir C:/dtmp
ECHO USER username > script.ftp
ECHO PASSWORD password > script.ftp
ECHO cd Directories-files > script.ftp
ECHO lcd C:/dtmp > script.ftp
ECHO binary > script.ftp
ECHO prompt n > script.ftp
ECHO get main.py > script.ftp
:: Use the temporary script for unattended FTP
:: Note: depending on your OS version you may have to add a '-n' switch
FTP -v -s:script.ftp domain.lt
:: For the paranoid: overwrite the temporary file before deleting it
TYPE NUL >script.ftp
DEL script.ftp
GOTO End
:End
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few immediate problems I can see.

The first is the use of the wrong slash in your `mkdir` command (and that's the one causing your specific error). It should be:

```
mkdir c:\dtmp
```

The second problem is the fact that you should be *appending* most of those commands to the FTP script:

```
ECHO USER username         > script.ftp
ECHO PASSWORD password    >> script.ftp
ECHO cd Directories-files >> script.ftp
ECHO lcd C:/dtmp          >> script.ftp
ECHO binary               >> script.ftp
ECHO prompt n             >> script.ftp
ECHO get main.py          >> script.ftp
```

The way you have it, every echo replaces the file, so the script will end up consisting of the single line `get main.py` which won't work because you haven't logged in.

Thirdly, since you're logging in *within* the script, you should disable auto login as well, by using the `-n` option to ftp (though I see that's mentioned in a comment after a closer look):

```
ftp -n -v -s:script.ftp domain.lt
```

---

Another thing to look at is the fact that some FTP clients don't have a PASSWORD command, they supply it on the USER line. So try changing:

```
ECHO USER username         > script.ftp
ECHO PASSWORD password    >> script.ftp
```

to:

```
ECHO USER username password > script.ftp
```

(and ensuring that your username and password are correct of course).

Failing *that,* simply start up an FTP session without the `-s` and see what's going wrong by entering each of the FTP commands individually:

```
C:\Pax> ftp -n wopr.dod.gov
Connected to wopr.dod.gov.
220-FTPD DOD FTP at WOPR.DOD.GOV, 07:28:59 on 2011-08-19.
220 SHALL WE PLAY A GAME?
ftp> user sfalken joshua
331 Send password please.
530 PASS command failed
Login failed.
ftp> bye
221 Quit command received. Goodbye.
```

Comment: Now throws - "Please login with USER and PASS"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

ftp -n wopr.dod.gov
user sfalken
pass joshua
bye

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for trailing spaces on the user/password when creating the FTP script file e.g.

ECHO USER username > script.ftp

Should be:
ECHO USER username> script.ftp